# Internet connection for Wireless Laptop & Wired PC through Belkin Router

Tags: laptop

I’ve one desktop PC & one Laptop (The Laptop does support wireless connection). I’ve also got a Belkin Router and my ISP has provided broadband connection directly to my desktop PC. The desktop PC has got two LAN cards. One LAN card is occupying the broadband connection and another is idle.

Now I want Internet connection by using the Router for Wireless Laptop.

How can I share the Internet connection for my Laptop?

Comment: I removed your IP address from this post. You never want to expose your IP directly like that

Answer (score 0):

So the ISP ran a cable to the Router from their system, and a Cat5/6 cable from the Router to the PC?  Does the Router also support wireless?   If so then all you need to do is establish the WiFi connection between the Laptop and Router.  The SSID and security key should have been given to you at installation, or may be printed on the router.